# Polymer Firebase. Unable to optimise .html

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

[image: The problem Im getting]

Why Am I getting this error message on `polymer build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a syntax error in one of my divs.. Once I fixed that. It Builds just fine